# not able to connect angular with rest api

Tags: angular

this is my user.service.ts module and it is not working
baseurl is my sql table url and i am not getting its record on angular page

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from './user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  private baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getUsersList(): Observable<User[]>{

    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>(`${this.baseURL}`);
  }
```

this is my component code where i am calling service please help me to get out of this issue

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { User } from '../user';
    import { UserService } from '../user.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-user-list',
      templateUrl: './user-list.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./user-list.component.css']
    })
    export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
    
      users: User[];
    
      constructor(private userService: UserService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
    
        
    
        this.getUsers();
      }
    
      private getUsers(){
    
        this.userService.getUsersList().subscribe(data => {
          this.users = data;
        });
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Is there any error? And make sure that you have subscribed to this observable.

Comment: As @tufonas mentioned above you need to subscribe to "getUsersList" in order to trigger the call. I recently had a similar situation where I could not get data from the backend due to me not subscribing to the call.

Comment: Can we see the component code where this service function is called?

Comment: i had add component code and please tell me how to subscribe to this observable ...i am new to this technology

Comment: @tufonas no error were there

Comment: Use console.log to check what is being returned from your http call